# How to increase spark streaming receivers

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

My spark streaming application monitors a directory using

> filestream .

How to increase number of receivers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitoring a directory doesn't have the same receiver challenges that other Spark Streaming receivers face. Since its a filestream Spark is able to use the standard mechanism whereby the workers directly read from the file. As per the programming guide "Every input DStream (except file stream, discussed later in this section) is associated with a Receiver (Scala doc, Java doc) object which receives the data from a source and stores it in Spark’s memory for processing." So this isn't a worry :)